# How to show list of calendars

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit, ekcalendar

In my project i need to show list of calendars where user can select one, based on selection i need to fetch the events from device calendar app. Is there any way to show the default calendar list like the below image or should i customise the view

https://www.systutorials.com/136133/changing-iphone-holiday-calendar-local-one/holiday-calendar-iphone-us/

Please help this out.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `EKEventStore`?

Comment: sorry man. i didnt

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: Look at the documentation for EventKit and EventKitUI. Scan the class lists and you will quickly find what you need.

Comment: thats very helpful. tq so much

Comment: if you know what im looking for.. could you tell me if it is possible or not

Comment: Did you scan those classes lists from those two frameworks? Please do. One of those classes is obviously what you are looking for.

Comment: Im showing the list of calendars in my app. but what i want is to show the default device calendars list. i scanned these EKEventkit  & store, in those frameworks, mentioned only about how to get calendars

Answer (score 1):

To display the view in your screenshot you want to use `EKCalendarChooser`. You can specify behaviors in response to user selections via `EKCalendarChooserDelegate`. Check out Apple's docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkitui/ekcalendarchooser

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try to use Cocoa pods where there are a huge number of calendar pods which you can easily use by just importing it.

1. [JTAppleCalendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar)
2. [Calendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Calendar)
3. [XCalender](https://cocoapods.org/pods/XCalender)

and there are many more that you can have a look at.

click on this [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) to get more cocoa pods example.

Answer (score 0):

```
     let calendars =EventStore.calendars(for entityType:.Events)
```

// TO fetch Events

```
    let eventStore = EventsManager.getEventStore()



    var tempArray:[EKEvent] = []



    let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: startdate, end: endDate, calendars: calendars)//nil will include all the calendars

    let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate) as [EKEvent]
```

To fetch meetings from the calendar use this 
`Create your own UI with table view and sections and request permissions for Calendar . Then fetch calendars from the eventStore using .